# Clear value JSON

Tags: python, json

I am getting an error when returning JSON, apparently it is because of "0" of the dictionary, but the dictionary has that structure, I guess there is some way to remove "0", I leave the following code to know if this is possible

````
d = json.loads('{ "jsonrpc": "2.0", "id": "1", "result": [ 0, {"ubus_rpc_session": "d8f4cec54d08c3f1d5581ec6135992e7","timeout": 300,"expires": 300,"acls": {"access-group": {"superuser": ["read","write"],"unauthenticated": ["read"]},"ubus": {"*": ["*"],"session": ["access","login"]},"uci": {"*": ["read","write"]}},"data": {"username": "root"}}]}')

#print d

for i in d["result"]:

    if 'ubus_rpc_session' in i:
        print i['ubus_rpc_session']
```

if 'ubus_rpc_session' in i:
TypeError: argument of type 'int' is not iterable
````

Comment: plz check my answer if it completes the requirement.

Answer (score 1):

check below code , its written with python three hence print has other syntax.

```
import json
d = json.loads('{ "jsonrpc": "2.0", "id": "1", "result": [ 0, {"ubus_rpc_session": "d8f4cec54d08c3f1d5581ec6135992e7","timeout": 300,"expires": 300,"acls": {"access-group": {"superuser": ["read","write"],"unauthenticated": ["read"]},"ubus": {"*": ["*"],"session": ["access","login"]},"uci": {"*": ["read","write"]}},"data": {"username": "root"}}]}')

#print d
#print(type(d['result'][1]))

i = d['result'][1]['ubus_rpc_session']
print(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

You got an error because the value of key `'result'` is a list and and 'ubus_rpc_session' is a key inside a dictionary of the list. Put simply, the value is like [int, dict].

So `d['result']` gives [int, dict...]
On  your first iteration, you are checking if 'ubus_rpc_session' is in int, which is wrong (so a `TypeError`). A possible solve to this, remove the int and get the dict element only.

```
value_dict = d.get("results")[1] #dict is at index 1 in the value of 'results' key
if 'ubus_rpc_session' in value_dict:
....#Do Something
```